# App crashing when tapping on UIBarButtonItem in Swift

Tags: swift

thanks in advance to anyone who helps me out with this (This is my first StackOverflow question!)

Anyway, I'm playing with Swift in Xcode 6 beta 6, and I can not for the life of me figure out how to get the action of my UIBarButtonItem to fire correctly. When I tap on the button, I get a crash and the console spits out an unrecognized selector error. I'm sure I'm doing something really stupid, but here is the code I'm trying:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       //
        let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, target: self, action: "buttonTapped")



        self.title = "A Swift Application"
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

func buttonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    println("Tapped")
}
```

I've tried adding a colon to the end of the action parameter in the buttons initialization statement. Again, thanks in advance to whoever helps me out!

Answer (score 0):

Your button declaration should look like this:

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, target: self, action: "buttonTapped:")
```

That is, your action parameter should have a colon after it because your buttonTapped function has a parameter. If your buttonTapped() function looked like this:

```
func buttonTapped(){}
```

then it would work.